# For loop with ArrayList - Process data by data

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I've the following code, a for loop. I want to process small amounts of data in every iteration.

```java
ArrayList uniqueSTA = q.getUniqueStations("localserver");
```

returns an `ArrayList` of Strings that represent a STA, let's say a computer (name, price, etc)

```java
dadosSTA = q.getStationData(uniqueSTA.get(i).toString(), "localserver");
```

`dadosSTA` represents and `ArrayList` of `Dados` objects, it holds all the information about a specific computer, like name, price etc.

```java
dataForPPong = p.detectPP(5, 3, dadosSTA);
```

is to detect an event.

Now I need to do this for each STA and STA by STA.

Pseudo code:

1. Get all STA -> returns something like STA1, STA2, STA3, STA4...
2. Get all data from STA1
3. Detect PP for STA1
4. Save in the array
5. go back to 1) and do for STA2 and so on

This is my code.

```
    ArrayList<Dados> dadosSTA = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Dados> dataForPPong = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList uniqueSTA = q.getUniqueStations("localserver");

    for(int i = 0; i<uniqueSTA.size(); i++)
    {

        dadosSTA = q.getStationData(uniqueSTA.get(i).toString(), "localserver");

        dataForPPong = p.detectPP(5, 3, dadosSTA);

    }
```

**EDIT**

It seems i wasn't clear so here's an explanation of whats my problem:

Lets say that the array dadosSTA has [STA1] then [STA1] is processed with p.detectPP. Next loop dadosSTA has [STA1,STA2] and it is processed with p.detectPP but the problem here is that STA1 has already been processed before. 
The same happens for all next cycles, like the 3rd dadosSTA has [STA1,STA2,STA3] and it is processed with p.detectPP but STA1 and STA2 has already been processed in the previous loops.

What I want is to tweak the code in order to no process what has already been processed before and I'm quite sure the problem is inside the for loop.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't want it to re-process the data that he as already processed in the cycles before. I've tried to create a temporary ArrayList at the beginning of each cycle and at the end of the cycle add the processed data to the final array but I get a heap error, looks like I ran out of memory. My data is around 50 000 records.

Comment: q.getStationData(uniqueSTA.get(i).toString(), "localserver"); what does this function do ? or please try to make it clear where do you think you have repeated processing..

Comment: it returns all the data to process with p.detectPP(5, 3, dadosSTA);

Comment: from where does getStationData return it ? from uniqueSTA or q ?

Comment: getStationData returns ArrayList<Dados>

Comment: ok .. can you just tell me where does the re-processing occur ? I read your code more than 10x times :) but I cannot understand your problem yet

Comment: Ok, lets say that the array dadosSTA has [STA1] then [STA1] is processed with p.detectPP. Next loop dadosSTA has [STA1,STA2] and it is processed with p.detectPP but the problem here is that STA1 has already been processed before. The same happens for all next cycles, like the 3rd dadosSTA has [STA1,STA2,STA3] and it is processed with p.detectPP but STA1 and STA2 has already been processed in the previous loops.

Comment: I don't want it to reprocess data that has already been processed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your point correctly .. your problem is that you are processing list of data.. the solution is easy .. I edited your code :

```
            HashMap<String, Boolean> processedList = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

then

```
            String nameSTA = "localserver";
            if (!processedList.containsKey(nameSTA) || !processedList.get(nameSTA)) {

                processedList.put(nameSTA, false);
                ArrayList<Dados> dadosSTA = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList<Dados> dataForPPong = new ArrayList();

                ArrayList uniqueSTA = q.getUniqueStations(nameSTA);

                for (int i = 0; i < uniqueSTA.size(); i++) {

                    dadosSTA = q.getStationData(uniqueSTA.get(i)
                            .toString(), nameSTA);
                    dataForPPong = p.detectPP(5, 3, dadosSTA);
                }
                processedList.put(nameSTA, true);
            }
```

I consider the STA#1 name is "localserver" .. so I check if it doenst exist in processedList or it exists with false state .. so you can process it ..

====== update ======

if you have STA1,STA2  together, it will be a different implementation :

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> processedList = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

then

```
ArrayList<Dados> dadosSTA = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Dados> dataForPPong = new ArrayList();

ArrayList uniqueSTA = q.getUniqueStations("localserver");

for (int i = 0; i < uniqueSTA.size(); i++) {
    String dtl=uniqueSTA.get(i).toString();


    if (!processedList.containsKey(dtl) || !processedList.get(dtl)) {
        dadosSTA = q.getStationData(dtl, "localserver");
        dataForPPong = p.detectPP(5, 3, dadosSTA);
        processedList.put(nameSTA, true);
    }
}
```

I suppose that dtl is a unique value ..

Comment: Dont tell me that all data are mixed in uniqueSTA I mean STA1, later STA1,STA2 or STA1,STA2,...

Comment: If found the mistake in my code. I was using a global variable instead of a local variable. This problem was inside the method getStationData.